# Manytomany field in Django mongoengine Document

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following Django model:

```
from mongoengine import *
from datetime import datetime

class Company(Document):

    name = StringField(max_length=500)



class Feedback(Document):

    text = StringField(max_length=500)
    is_approved = BooleanField(default=False)
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

I want to add a manytomany field of Feedback in Company

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Anto this is not a Django model, it's a mongoengine Document. Django's documentation will be of no help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a Django model, but a mongoengine `Document`. It does not have `ManyToManyField`. Instead you should probably add a `ReferenceField` inside a `ListField` to your `Company` class, like this:

```
class Company(Document):
    name = StringField(max_length=500)
    feedbacks = ListField(ReferenceField(Feedback))

class Feedback(Document):
    text = StringField(max_length=500)
    is_approved = BooleanField(default=False)
    date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Source: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#one-to-many-with-listfields

Comment: I have one more doubt in this topic. ***i cant add feedback object in Company.feedbacks.*** please help me.

Comment: Please check out the link I gave as source. I believe it has pretty concise examples.

Comment: @VasilyAlexeev 
Is there has any errors when I am saving the Company object without a Feedback Instance
How can I add required = False inside feedbacks = ListField(ReferenceField(Feedback)).

Comment: @VarnanK I think changing it like this should help: `feedbacks = ListField(ReferenceField(Feedback), default=list)`